# SynchronizedCollection in Silverlight

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight, synchronized

I need to ensure the collection is safely accessed by a number of threads. 
For that purpose I used `SynchronizedCollection` in my project
in .NET. Now I'm dealing with Silverlight project and I face the same problem -
a collection must be thread-safe.

I think that `SynchronizedCollection` is not available
in Silverlight. What is the approach to achieve the goal?

Is there a solution that might be applied both to Silverlight and .NET 4.0?

Thanks in advance for the replies and clues!

Cheers

Comment: If you don't need high performance you can simply wrap the access to the collection in a `lock` statement.

Comment: @CodeInChaos, well, I actually NEED high performance